# How do I set up git in deploy.rb in a rails 4 app using mina?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, mina

I am trying to use mina to deploy my app to a digital ocean server and have a git repo on bitbucket. I was able to run `mina setup' just fine, but when I run`mina deploy` I get an error.

my deploy.rb

```
require 'mina/bundler'
require 'mina/rails'
require 'mina/git'
require 'mina/rbenv'  # for rbenv support. (http://rbenv.org)
# require 'mina/rvm'    # for rvm support. (http://rvm.io)

# Basic settings:
#   domain       - The hostname to SSH to.
#   deploy_to    - Path to deploy into.
#   repository   - Git repo to clone from. (needed by mina/git)
#   branch       - Branch name to deploy. (needed by mina/git)

set :rails_env, 'production' 
set :domain, 'my.server'
set :deploy_to, '/home/deployer/mysite'
set :repository, 'git@bitbucket.org:me/myproject.git'
set :branch, 'master'
set :user, 'deployer'
set :forward_agent, true
set :port, '22'


# Manually create these paths in shared/ (eg: shared/config/database.yml) in your server.
# They will be linked in the 'deploy:link_shared_paths' step.
set :shared_paths, ['config/database.yml', 'log', 'config/secrets.yml']

# Optional settings:
#   set :user, 'foobar'    # Username in the server to SSH to.
#   set :port, '30000'     # SSH port number.

# This task is the environment that is loaded for most commands, such as
# `mina deploy` or `mina rake`.
task :environment do
  # If you're using rbenv, use this to load the rbenv environment.
  # Be sure to commit your .rbenv-version to your repository.
  queue %{
    echo "-----> Loading environment"  
    #{echo_cmd %[source ~/.bashrc]}
  }
  invoke :'rbenv:load'

  # For those using RVM, use this to load an RVM version@gemset.
  # invoke :'rvm:use[ruby-1.9.3-p125@default]'
end

# Put any custom mkdir's in here for when `mina setup` is ran.
# For Rails apps, we'll make some of the shared paths that are shared between
# all releases.
task :setup => :environment do
  queue! %[mkdir -p "#{deploy_to}/shared/log"]
  queue! %[chmod g+rx,u+rwx "#{deploy_to}/shared/log"]

  queue! %[mkdir -p "#{deploy_to}/shared/config"]
  queue! %[chmod g+rx,u+rwx "#{deploy_to}/shared/config"]

  queue! %[touch "#{deploy_to}/shared/config/database.yml"]
  queue  %[echo "-----> Be sure to edit 'shared/config/database.yml'."]

  queue! %[touch "#{deploy_to}/shared/config/secrets.yml"]
  queue %[echo "-----> Be sure to edit 'shared/config/secrets.yml'."]
end

desc "Deploys the current version to the server."
task :deploy => :environment do
  deploy do
    # Put things that will set up an empty directory into a fully set-up
    # instance of your project.
    invoke :'git:clone'
    invoke :'deploy:link_shared_paths'
    invoke :'bundle:install'
    invoke :'rails:db_migrate'
    invoke :'rails:assets_precompile'

    to :launch do
      invoke :'passenger:restart'
    end
  end
end

desc "Restarts the nginx server."  
task :restart do  
  invoke :'passenger:restart'
end

namespace :passenger do  
  task :restart do
    queue "mkdir #{deploy_to}/current/tmp; touch #{deploy_to}/current/tmp/restart.txt"
  end
end  

# For help in making your deploy script, see the Mina documentation:
#
#  - http://nadarei.co/mina
#  - http://nadarei.co/mina/tasks
#  - http://nadarei.co/mina/settings
#  - http://nadarei.co/mina/helpers
```

When I do "mina deploy", I get this error

```
-----> Loading environment        
-----> Loading rbenv        
-----> Creating a temporary build path        
-----> Cloning the Git repository        
       Cloning into bare repository '/home/deployer/mysite/scm'...
       Host key verification failed.
       fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

       Please make sure you have the correct access rights
       and the repository exists.
 !     ERROR: Deploy failed.   
-----> Cleaning up build        
       Unlinking current 
       OK 

 !     Command failed.
       Failed with status 19
```

I have ssh keys set up on bitbucket and Im able to push my repo to it just fine from my computer, I also have an ssh key from my server set up on bitbucket (not sure if it is needed, but I thought i would try it). What could be wrong?

Comment: did you ever figure out how to fix this?

Answer (score 4):

add this in your deploy.rb file

```
set :term_mode, nil
```

make sure that you have added server SSH public key on github

Comment: This was the solution for me; with multiple ssh keys and alias in .ssh/config

Comment: hmm would be nice to know why this works (especially when it used to work without this before)

Answer (score 1):

You can use your local ssh keys for this.

Use the [-A setting](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=ssh&sektion=1) of SSH. and set it in mina like `set :port, '22 -A'` this will append the -A to the ssh command issued by Mina.

Basically it forwards the authentication you use on your deployment server. (like `set :forward_agent, true` does in Capistrano)

---

I think best practice however, is to generate a ssh key on the server and set it as a deploy key in your hosted SCM solution.

Comment: Their config already has a `set :forward_agent, true`, which does basically what you're suggesting (adding the `-A` flag to the ssh command)

Comment: It is a worse practice to generate ssh key in server.

Answer (score -3):

Your server tries to git from *git@bitbucket.org:me/myproject.git*, but there is host key at your server.
You can copy your `id_rsa.pub` and `known_host`s file through `scp` command on server and then run it again. It will work.